# How many $2048$ bit primes with the form $2q+1$ are there?

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $p,q$ are prime and $p = 2q+1$. Assuming that the likelihood of $q$ and $2q+1$ being prime are independent, how many $2048$ bit primes with the form $2q+1$ do you expect exist?

Comment: Is this a homework question?  What have you tried so far?  Does '2048-bit' mean from $1$ to $2^{2048}-1$ (i.e. 2048 bits or less), or just from $2^{2047}$ to $2^{2048}-1$?

Comment: This is not homework. I found it in a textbook and thought it was interesting. I'm not sure how to solve the problem, but I know that Sophie Germain primes are not so rare. I'm having trouble conceptualizing how I can determine just how many primes there are. And $2048$ bit means $2^{2047}$ to $2^{2048}-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few broad hints, to leave you something to do for yourself:

1. We say that 'the probability' of a number $x$ being prime is $\frac1{\ln x}$, in the sense that the [Prime Number Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) states that there are approximately $\frac{x}{\ln x}$ primes less than $x$ — and more to the point, the number of primes between $x$ and $x+n$ is approximately $\frac{n}{\ln x}$, when $n\in O(x)$ (you can convince yourself that the PNT implies that this holds to first order whenever $n\lt cx$ for arbitrary constant $c$).  Given this, you should be able to figure out (approximately) how many primes $q$ there are between $2^{2046}$ and $2^{2047}-1$ (i.e., those for which $2q+1$ will be a number in your original $2048$-bit range).
2. Once you have an approximate count of the $2047$-bit primes, you can multiply this number by the probability that a random number between $2^{2047}$ and $2^{2048}-1$ is prime — which is, of course, very similar to the (probability) value you just computed above.  But there's one subtle catch here: the numbers you're testing aren't 'generic' numbers in the relevant range, they're specifially *odd* numbers; it turns out that this has an effect on the probability.  Essentially, the probability that an odd number is prime is twice the probability that an arbitrary number is prime; intuitively, this is because there are $n$ numbers in e.g. the interval $(x, x+n)$ (of which $\approx\frac{n}{\ln x}$ are prime, as mentioned above), but there are only $\frac n2$ odd numbers in that interval and all the primes will be found among them.

Comment: Did you mean $n \in o(x)$ rather than $n \in O(x)$?

Comment: Interestingly, I would have done the analysis in the opposite way: count the 2048-bit primes, then estimate how many of them have $(p-1)/2$ prime.

Comment: @Hurkyl I actually mean $n\in O(x)$; the estimate holds even if e.g. $n=20x$ (again, to first order - there's a $\frac{x}{\ln^2 x}$ term, of course, coming from the fact that $\ln n=\ln x+C$).  That's important here because in this case we have $n\approx x$ (e.g., $x=2^{2046}$, $n=2^{2046}-1$).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Using $x = 2^{2046}$ and $n = (2^{2047}-1)-2^{2046}$ will give me the number of $2047$ bit primes?

Comment: @user1038665 Yes, but with poor approximation, because your $n=x-1$...

Comment: @Vadim Again, the approximation isn't actually all that bad - to first order the formula is pretty good.

Comment: @user1038665 Yes, but better still for getting the initial count is to use $\pi(x)\approx \frac{x}{\ln x}$ first with $x=2^{2046}$ and then with $x=2^{2047}$ and to subtract the former from the latter.

Comment: You might want to bring in the fact that if $q=2p+1$, then $q\equiv 5 \pmod{6}$ and $p\equiv 5 \pmod{6}$. Hence, this (approximately) halves your count by Dirichlet's Theorem.

Comment: @CalvinLin Are you sure that halves the count?  That seems like it would follow 'automatically' from the conditioning - i.e., if you only count e.g. those $p\equiv 5\pmod 6$ then you already know that $3\nmid q$ so you have to raise the 'innate' probability of $q$ being prime, similarly to how you have to accomodate for the known fact that $q$ is odd.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki [Dirichlet density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_density) gives us the (relative) result. Though, if you look at the (absolute) difference, it is bounded away from 0.

Comment: @Calvin: In fact, for every odd prime $r$ of less than 2047 bits, we need $p \not\neq 1 \bmod{r}$.